# Получение значение с textarea CKEditor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

не могу получить текст с CKEditor с поля textarea.
У меня есть подключенный в head CDN  `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Далее разметка :

```
    <form id="compose_form" method="post">
<div id="editor">

    <textarea id="editor" name="editor1" class="editor1" >This is sample text</textarea>
</div>
<button name="add_post" id="createPostBtn"  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  >Добавить запись</button>
</form>
```

Скрипт через который я пытаюсь получить значение textarea :

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );



    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#createPostBtn').on('click',function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

            var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
            console.log(editorText);
        });
    });

</script>
```

При нажатии на кнопку в консоли ошибка **Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined**
Что я не так делаю ? Почему ошибка и правильно ли написан код для получения значения с textarea ? Собираюсь потом аяксом отправлять в пхп обработчик

Comment: `document.querySelector( '#editor' ).innerHTML` вернет значение textarea.. что касается ошибки - переведите ее в гугле, там прямым текстом написано - переменной `CKEDITOR`  не существует

Comment: Jour, Ваш код работает , но он мне возвращает " <textarea id="editor" name="editor1">This is sample text</textarea> " , как можно получить только содержимое ?

Comment: Открываем консоль разработчика, редактируем body и вставляем туда `<textarea id="editor" name="editor1" class="editor1" >This is sample text</textarea>` после чего в консоль пишем `document.querySelector( '#editor' ).innerHTML` или `document.querySelector( '#editor' ).value` (в данном случае разницы нет)... получаем `This is sample text`

Comment: Да , значение получаю , спасибо большое , но функционал CKEditor не работает . Когда я делаю текст жирным или курсивным , соответственно , у меня должны при отправке содержимого отправляться еще и теги но у меня отправляется только обычный текст без тегов

Comment: почему у вас не работает CKEditor я не в курсе) Значение из textarea получить удалось - замечательно. Разберитесь, откуда у вас берется переменная `CKEDITOR` - на данный момент она не существует.